# Уточнение присоединяется тире, - плохо смотрится?

Tags: пунктуация

> И пусть даже что-то оказалось утерянным... Впрочем, древние знали, что
>   роспись *в нижнем регистре* стен плохо сохраняется и присутствие даже
>   нескольких человек затрудняет восприятие, поэтому пространство стен
>   снизу и чуть выше человеческого роста **расписывали различными
>   имитациями – каменной инкрустации или ткани** (в некоторых дворцах ещё
>   встречается).

Курсив автора.

Comment: Уточнение - это когда уточняют **какие** иммитации, а здесь — иммитации **чего**. По-моему, никакие знаки препинания не нужны. Но кажется, автор хотел сказать другое: роспись иммитировала различные отделочные материалы.

Comment: Ну да, не нужны знаки... Щас пошлю, пусть думает. Мол, не одна я спотыкаюсь (=придираюсь).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...пространство стен снизу и чуть выше человеческого роста...*
Возникает ощущение, что это какое-то пространство снизу и какое-то — чуть выше человеческого роста. Необходимо обозначить его границы: снизу и до уровня (или до линии).

*...расписывали различными имитациями – каменной инкрустации или ткани...*
Мне кажется, что слово "различными" здесь лишнее (имитаций-то всего две).
Если же имеются в виду разные ткани и разные рисунки на камне, тогда необходимо множественное число.
Соседство "имитациями" и "инкрустациями" делает текст трудночитаемым. Я бы виды материалов поменяла местами. Тире не нужно.

**...поэтому пространство стен снизу и до уровня** [или до линии] **чуть выше человеческого роста расписывали имитациями ткани и каменной инкрустации (в некоторых дворцах ещё встречается).**

Или:
**...поэтому пространство стен снизу и до уровня** [или до линии] **чуть выше человеческого роста расписывали различными имитациями тканей и каменных инкрустаций (в некоторых дворцах ещё встречается).**

**Дополнение**
Собственно, в начале предложения уже указано: "роспись *в нижнем регистре* стен".
Думаю, что слова "стен снизу и" можно убрать (они почти повторяются).
Тогда получается:

Впрочем, древние знали, что роспись *в нижнем регистре* стен плохо сохраняется и присутствие даже нескольких человек затрудняет восприятие, поэтому пространство до уровня чуть выше человеческого роста расписывали имитациями ткани и каменной инкрустации (в некоторых дворцах ещё встречается).

Comment: Может и правда было две полосы? А если одна, то зачем здесь *и* (снизу и до уровня). Можно  просто "до уровня", можно "снизу (внизу) до уровня", можно "от пола и до уровня".

Comment: В предложении "...снизу **и** чуть выше...", поэтому я так и оставила. Внесла правку, может, ТАК лучше? (Конечно, если я поняла всё правильно.)